# How to create an iPod-esque UISlider

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, uislider

Does anyone have a quick way to make a UISlider that looks like the ones in the iPod app (think scrubber/volume control). Basically I need something that looks exactly like an MPVolumeView, but doesn't control sound. Failing that, does anyone have the assets to make one (the knob/track).

Comment: Its not just a plain UISlider?

Comment: No, a plain UISlider looks like http://www.blogcdn.com/www.tuaw.com/media/2007/09/slider.png
the one I'm going for looks like the one in this screenshot:
http://artoftheiphone.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/pop-ipod-controls-on-the-iphone.png

Comment: The only difference is its more glossy right?

Comment: Well, it's just a different appearance. I know how to create a custom UISlider, I was just wondering if someone had already created/extracted the images, see if I couldn't save myself some trouble.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah, I knew how to create the custom slider, I just wanted to know if anyone had the images already. I guess not, so I extracted my own.

For future reference, if anyone else needs to do this:

Gallery of assets below, 
http://img200.imageshack.us/gal.php?g=whiteslide.png

Download those images, and use this code to set it all up:

```
scrubberSlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
UIImage *stetchLeftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueTrack.png"]
                            stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:9.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
UIImage *stetchRightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteTrack.png"]
                             stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:9.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
[scrubberSlider setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteSlide.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[scrubberSlider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[scrubberSlider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks for providing links to assets. Exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to approximate the appearance you want (wouldn't guarantee **exact** likeness) by using

```
setThumbImage:forState:
setMinimumTrackImage:forState:
setMaximumTrackImage:forState:
```

on UISlider. (It's also not very hard to create your own slider, by subclassing UIControl.)